# gsoap 2.8.43 with onvif

Tags: gsoap, onvif

Does the onvif have any problem with gsoap 2.8.43 version?
we have two different vendors onvif camera (one is Cohu and one is Axis) that we need to test it under Oracle Linux 7.1 
If I use gsoap 2.8.17r wsdl2h with devicemgmt.wsdl and use GetSystemDateAndTime, I can get response with both camera. 
But with gsoap 2.8.43 with same code I cannot compile it.
It keep complain that 
main.cpp:26:98: error: no matching function for call to ‘DeviceBindingProxy::GetSystemDateAndTime(_tds__GetSystemDateAndTime*&, _tds__GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse*&)’
  result = proxy.GetSystemDateAndTime(tds__GetSystemDateAndTime, tds__GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse);

Any idea what I do wrong?

many thanks in advance

Comment: I know i may be late, but did you get any solution to your problem??

Answer (score 0):

Is the `GetSystemDateAndTime` function signature different when using wsdl2h 2.8.43? That might be the problem.

If so, then simply use the 2.8.17r version to generate the .h file and use the 2.8.43 version to generate all the rest with soapcpp2. You can use an older .h file generated with wsdl2h with a newer gSOAP version of soapcpp2 and libraries.